# ADODB - Creating a VBA Function to minimize repeated code?

Tags: sql, vba, function, adodb, recordset

i have the following code which gets data from a database table with ADODB and outputs to sheet.
I use this a lot, changing between cnn (access / mysql etc....) / different queries.

Is there a way i can create this as a function to minimize repeated code?

```
Sub getDBdata()
    Dim Cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

     Set Cnn = New ADODB.Connection
     Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\test\TESTDB.MDB"

     SQLString = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"

    rs.Open SQLString, Cnn, adLockReadOnly

    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close

    Cnn.Close
    Set Cnn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

example:

```
sub getSpecificData()

Connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\test\TESTDB.MDB"
SQLString = "SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1"
OutputLocation = Sheet1.Range("A1")

      getDBData Connection, SQLString, OutputLocation

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: A function will work. [An object will work even better](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46312/23788)

Comment: Thankyou, looks complex but will see if I can get this working

Comment: It's old code I wrote a while back... using a disconnected recordset rather than implementing a `ResultRow` class would make it much simpler. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to add 3 parameters to your sub:

```
Sub getDBdata(connString as string, SQL as String, rngDest As Range)
    Dim Cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set Cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Cnn.Open connString
    rs.Open SQL, Cnn, adLockReadOnly
    rngDest.CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Cnn.Close
    Set Cnn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you :) this is all i needed and ive got it working

Comment: if i was to use vaData = rs.GetRows so the data is stored in array. After the sub has ended vaData empties. Is there a way to keep the array data after closing the connection ?

Comment: If you want to return an array of data then remove the third parameter and make it a function.

Comment: i got it working, I created a separate sub without the third parameter, then declared vaData as public

Comment: You should try to avoid that way of doing things - when you don’t need global variables it’s best to not use them